# (VSE) How do I speed up audio by more than 10 times?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm trying to speed up some video by a factor of 20, audio included. The video strip is easy: I just add a speed control transform strip. The audio part isn't as easy. Transform strips don't work on sound strips, so normally I use the Pitch Control feature on the audio strip. Unfortunately, it looks like there's a hard-coded limit of 10 on this:

```
  prop = RNA_def_property(srna, "pitch", PROP_FLOAT, PROP_NONE);
  RNA_def_property_float_sdna(prop, NULL, "pitch");
  RNA_def_property_range(prop, 0.1f, 10.0f);
  RNA_def_property_ui_text(prop, "Pitch", "Playback pitch of the sound");
```

Can this limit be overridden somehow (without recompiling Blender)? Is there any other way of changing the audio speed more than a factor of 10?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in Blender, but you could always speed up the audio in another program such as Audacity (which is free and open source).  In Audacity, you just have to drag and drop the audio file into the program, drag to select the entire audio strip, and go into Effects -> Change Speed.  Then you can go into File -> Export to save it and then import it back into Blender.

Comment: Yeah, but as I'm dealing with the audio track which is part of a video clip which has already been cut in the VSE, that would end up being a synchronisation nightmare, so I very much want a pure Blender solution.

Comment: I don't use VSE, but hardcoded limit of just 10 is a really odd choice... Perhaps ask the devs.

Comment: @DavidGiven Maybe you should leave a note on the subject here: https://blender.chat/channel/vse
(If the link doesn't work in your browser, then try https://blender.chat/ click the globus icon and find the vse channel that way)

Sounds like a quick fix patch.